# Spring Batch - Item Processor with Hibernate AssertionError

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-batch

I have a strange problem concerning a chunk processing which is parallelized with a task executor.
The items are read via a JpaPagingItemReader. 
Sometimes I received in my ItemProcessor a nebulous problem and I absolutely don't know why :-(

The ItemProcessor received EntityBeans which are the result of the JpaPagingItemReader (**jpavendor: Hibernate**).

```
   @Override
    public DocumentRequestType process(CmabAuftrag cmabAuftrag) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.info(String.format("start process cmabauftrag %s - working thread %s",
                cmabAuftrag.getAuftragsId(), Thread.currentThread().getId()));

    String docContainer = cmabAuftrag.getArcoOid().getContainer();
```

The last statement generates now and again errors, not in a constant manner!

```
21:43:20 java.lang.AssertionError
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.EntityEntryContext.addEntityEntry(EntityEntryContext.java:125)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addEntry(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:505)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addEntity(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:462)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.addUninitializedEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:360)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:310)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:251)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:107)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:255)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:129)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:138)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:502)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:467)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:212)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:145)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:976)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:173)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
21:43:20    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
21:43:20    at de.axa.batch.ecmcm.cmab.persistence.domain.CmabArchivContainer_$$_jvst5ca_1.getContainer(CmabArchivContainer_$$_jvst5ca_1.java)
21:43:20    at de.axa.batch.ecmcm.cmab.core.batch.process.MidxRequestItemProcessor.process(MidxRequestItemProcessor.java:80)
21:43:20    at
```

This happens while reading the container attribute from a Entity which is part of the parent Entity **CmabAuftrag**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CMAB_AUFTRAG")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idGenerator", sequenceName = "SEQ_CMAB_AUFTRAG_AUFTRAGS_ID")
public class CmabAuftrag implements Serializable {
...........
    @JoinColumn(name = "ARCO_OID", referencedColumnName = "OID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CmabArchivContainer arcoOid;
```

**CmabArchivcontainer:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CMAB_ARCHIV_CONTAINER")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idGenerator", sequenceName = "SEQ_CMAB_ARCHIV_CONTAINER_OID")
public class CmabArchivContainer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "OID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idGenerator")
    private Long oid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "CONTAINER")
    private String container;
.....
    public String getContainer() {
        return container;
    }
```

Enclose the chunk configuration of my job (*as a hint: taskExecutor concurrencyLimit is set to 2 in this test configuration case*).

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" scope="step">
    <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="2"/>
</bean>

<batch:job id="processMasterindexJob" job-repository="jobRepository" restartable="false" parent="baseJob">
      <batch:step id="midxStep" parent="stepParent">
             <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" task-executor="taskExecutor">
                    <batch:chunk
                           reader="processMidxDbItemReader"
                           processor="midxItemProcessor"
                           writer="midxCompositeItemWriter"
                           processor-transactional="false"
                           reader-transactional-queue="false"
                           skip-limit="${cmab.batch.skip.limit}"
                           commit-interval="#{jobParameters['toProcess']==T(de.axa.batch.ecmcm.cmab.util.CmabConstants).TYPE_POSTAUSGANG ? '${consumer.global.pa.midx.readCount}' : '${consumer.global.pe.midx.readCount}' }"
                           cache-capacity="20">
                        <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
```

..................

I'm absolutely clueless why the process fails in receiving the attribute of the referenced entity bean CmabArchivContainer.

```
    String docContainer = cmabAuftrag.getArcoOid().getContainer();
```

What I'm observed is that the taskExecutor induced that the itemProcess is processed in the same time.

```
    21:43:20 2016-08-02 21:43:20,115 INFO   MidxRequestItemProcessor process 52 - start process cmabauftrag 2 - working thread 61
    21:43:20 2016-08-02 21:43:20,115 INFO   MidxRequestItemProcessor process 52 - start process cmabauftrag 3 - working thread 62
    21:43:20 Hibernate: select cmabarchiv0_.OID as OID1_2_0_, cmabarchiv0_.CONTAINER as CONTAINER2_2_0_ from CMAB_ARCHIV_CONTAINER cmabarchiv0_ where cmabarchiv0_.OID=?
    21:43:20 2016-08-02 21:43:20,127 WARN   LogRetryListener onError 36 - ------------------- START RETRY OPERATION
    .......
21:43:20 2016-08-02 21:43:20,129 DEBUG  MidxRequestItemProcessor mapPostausgangsDocToRequestType 104 - map postausgang to midx request for auftragsid 2
```

The Retry Operation is caused by the AssertionError (see above) and depends on cmabAuftrag <3>. 
Well, what could be the reason why the element "container" couldn't be "read" from the second entity CmabArchivContainer (cmabAuftrag = 3) within a concurrency environment?

Unfortunately I really stuck and haven't no clue :-(

Any helps will be very appreciated!

Many thanks in advance and regards,

Bodo

Comment: "Sometimes I received..." and "now and again errors, not in a constant manner!" indicates to me a threading issue. According to http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.html your reader needs to be set to saveState=false if used in a multi-threaded client (no restart available). Have you done this?

Comment: He, yes, the ItemReader its property "saveState" is set to false.

Comment: I could solve this problem if I specified the CmabArchivContainer relationship within the CmabAuftrag Entity with FetchType.EAGER!
Means the JpaPagingItemReader receives all entities wich are further relevant to process this step.
But I haven't any clue why FetchType.LAZY is not working in this context?!?!  Means, that I found a solution that isn't satisfying me!
So the question is still open ;-)